# Oracle function or package to execute SQL and return records

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, function, package

I need to call a package or function from Excel and cause the processing to be done on the server rather than on the local machine. To do this I need to pass a SELECT SQL statement to a package or function and it will return the record set.

The reason for this is that we have 100s of SQL statements that are currently processed in Excel but due to VPN slowness they are taking much longer. I have tried a single package to run an SQL when called and it is *significantly* quicker. Any approach to pass only SELECT SQL statements to a function and just return the records will be a great help.

Oracle version 11.

Comment: Running over a VPN would only affect throughput of the results from the server; it would not affect how efficiently the SQL runs in the database. Can you post a specific example of what you mean, with code and results? Are you saying that the SQL in Excel is running against records *already in Excel*, and you want it to run against records in the database instead?

Comment: All data is in oracle database. SQL is in excel vba and I connect to the database to run it, outputting the records to the empty worksheet.

For a 'complex' select SQL it takes 20 times longer over VPN than on networked PC. 
Simple SELECT from 1 table is still relatively quick.

So, I made a proof of concept to test the theory. I have an SQL which I run in Excel VBA and it takes 10 seconds to process. I make a package which runs that specific SQL and constructs a table of rows and it takes 1.3 seconds from Excel to call the package to get the records.

Comment: That actually makes no sense, as far as having anything to do with the VPN. VPN only affects network bandwidth, not the server's ability to process requests. There must be something different about the SQL itself, or the environment in which it was tested (e.g. the SQL session parameters, resource quotas, etc.). Did you run the package from within Excel, over the VPN, and get the exact same results back to Excel 85% faster? Please post some code examples of what you did with your PL/SQL package vs. the original SQL in Excel, and how you called it.

Comment: If you executed one query and then the other back-to-back, the second query from the function (depending on your exact implementation) could simply have been using the cached results of the first execution. That alone would explain the difference you saw. If you could also post the Explain Plan for each query version, that would also help confirm why one is faster than the other - whatever the reason is, you should confirm it so you can accurately repeat the results.

Comment: I agree it seems at odds with how VPN works. I have tested queries individually, in batches, interleaved and as part of larger processes and the timings are all consistent. When I'm on a networked PC it's fast and when i'm on VPN it's very slow. If I run an SQL in Excel it's slow and if I call a package with the same SQL it's fast. Our only way forward at the moment is to move all SQL to Oracle functions in a package which is a pain. - The only thing I can think of is that when called from Excel the processing over vpn is slow but if you force it to be processed on the server its fast.

Comment: "processing over vpn is slow but if you force it to be processed on the server its fast." That makes no sense: the SQL processing is *always* taking place on the server. VPN has *nothing* to do with it. VPN *only* affects how fast you can push packets of data over the wire. If the data is the same, then network throughput would be the same. If your results are that consistent, then something else *on the server* must be different about your execution. Perhaps the function is working on a "first_rows" basis and the raw SQL is returning "all_rows"? Be sure your result set is really the same.

Comment: There is as good or better chance that your function has just enough of a different execution plan from the optimizer that it just runs more efficiently (check the Explain Plans!). That can be fixed (most likely) with fresh table statistics generation, or other subtle changes to the SQL in Excel. Can you or have you tried using hints in your SQL like FIRST_ROWS? That would allow you to just modify the original SQL and avoid the package creation. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/BREAK.html#GUID-8C5811BC-01DF-4D95-A3A0-5C42C546534F.

Comment: Explain Plan usage: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/explain-plan-usage ; https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html#GUID-4A42068F-93FA-4E04-9574-1E96423C8EBC

Comment: If I had visibility on what Excel does when you connect and execute an SQL then I would know more as to why this happens. I don't and I can't change the SQL statements no matter how beneficial this might be. There are 100s.

The SQL run in the package is exactly the same as it is passed from Excel to the package. The reason I am looking at this approach is the same complex SELECT query, when run in TOAD, takes ~0.5 seconds. When I run a simple select statement in Excel it is quick. 

Combining these gives me:

1) make a table in DB 
2) select * from Table 

= very quick.

Comment: But, that aside, thank you very much for posting the link and your help with this. I will us that in future.

Comment: This is an interesting sounding problem, but way beyond what we can answer on this site. Rather than a question you should turn it into an advert for a short consultancy gig.

Comment: _"I need to call a package or function from Excel and cause the processing to be done on the server rather than on the local machine. "_   The processing of the SQL  _is_ done on the server, regardless of if you are calling a procedure or just asking the server to execute a plain SELECT.  I agree with the others that something else is going on.  But if we cannot see the code there's not much else we can do.

Comment: The example current process would be: Excel constructs an SQL statement in VBA 'SELECT * FROM Table1'. (only more complex) This is currently executed using ADODB.Connection. 10 seconds.
--------------
New process: Excel constructs the SQL into SQLQueryText variable. Then runs: 'select * from table(DBname.PackageName.FunctionName SQLQuerText)'. Oracle package creates a table definition, runs the SQL, Loops the cursor and transfers the data into table row using pipeline. Table is returned. 1.5 seconds for data to appear in Excel. How can I make it so that any SQL can be passed to the package.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses LOLA in comments.  It would help other users looking at this question to go ahead and [edit] your question, and add the additional details you provided in comments, to ensure all the details are in the question.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you access to Linux?

If you have created the statement and you only need the result of select in your output.
The most beautiful task is do:

SPOOL </my_folder/my_file.csv>

```
The below mentioned SELECT
```

SPOOL OFF;

If you create a SELECT statement like:

```
SELECT col1 || ';' || col2 || ';' || ... || ';' || coln FROM MY_TABLE;
```

You will have CSV file, wherever you run your Oracle.

If you must create the SELECT STATEMENT with variables,
You must work with REFCURSOR.

Regards.